# ctable position in classicthesis with lyx

Tags: positioning, lyx, ctable

I'm using the classicthesis package with ctable. Normally it works just fine, but I have one file ([chapter file](https://github.com/dkalisch/exchange/blob/master/Chapter01.lyx)) where I placed the following table with ctable:

```
\ctable[
    cap = {Übersicht der Teilstichproben},
    caption = {Übersicht der Teilstichproben\newline Quelle: \cite{Wagner:2008kq}},
label = Teilstichprobe,
width = 110mm,
pos   = ht,
center,
]{cc>{\hsize=1\hsize\raggedright}X}{
\tnote[a]{Genauer: Haushalte, deren Haushaltsvorstand nicht türkischer, italienischer, jugoslawischer. griechischer oder spanischer Nationalität war. Dies waren ganz überwiegend (99\thinspace\%)  deutsche Haushaltsvorstände.}
\tnote[b]{Genauer: Haushalte, deren Haushaltsvorstand türkischer, italienischer, jugoslawischer. griechischer oder spanischer Nationalität war.}
\tnote[c]{Anstaltshaushalte sind nicht repräsentativ eingeschlossen; sie werden zwar auch nicht ausgeschlossen, wenn sie beim random walk gelistet werden und sind insofern in dem Bruttobestand enthalten, werden aber bei der Durchführung der Befragung in der Regel bei neuen Samples nicht berücksichtigt.}
}{
    \FL
    Stichprobe & Start in & Beschreibung    \NN
    \cmidrule(l){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
    A & 1984 & (Deutsche) Haushalte\tmark[a] in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland (Hauptstichprobe, $N=4528$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    B & 1984 & Ausländische Haushalte\tmark[b] in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland ($N=1393$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    C & 1990 & Privathaushalte in der DDR ($N=2179$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    D & 1994 & Zuwanderer-Privathaushalte in Deutschland ($N=374$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    E & 1998 & Haushalte\tmark[c] in Deutschland (Ergänzungsstichprobe, $N=1056$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    F & 2000 & Haushalte\tmark[c] in Deutschland (Ergänzungsstichprobe, $N=6052$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    G & 2002 & Hocheinkommens-Privathaushalte in Deutschland (Hocheinkommensstichprobe, $N=1224$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    H & 2006 & Haushalte\tmark[c] in Deutschland, Ergänzungsstichprobe ($N=1506$ realisierte Haushalte)\LL
}
```

The problem is that the table is not displayed next to the position in the text, but at the very end. The other tables also got moved to the end. If I just use a small table like this

```
\ctable[
    cap = {Reduktion des Datensatzes},
    caption = {Reduktion des Datensatzes durch die Regeln},
label = Reduktion-Data,
width = 98mm,
pos   = ht,
center,
]{llrrr}{
}{
    \FL
    Regel &  & Reduktion & Kummuliert & Anzahl\NN
    \cmidrule(l){1-5}
                     & &       &        & 28329\NN
    {HHNR > 0}       & &       &      0 & 28329\NN
    {GEBJAHR < 1987} & & -5697 &  -5697 & 22632\NN
    {UPNAT == 1}     & & -4576 & -11955 & 16374\NN
    $gk_reg_a < 6$   & & -5187 & -17142 & 11187\LL
}
```

The table appears at the right spot or close to it, depending on the text.
The style files and the lyx file can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dkalisch/exchange).

Can someone help me please, because whatever I do, I can't figure out the mistake

Thanks for your help.

---

**UPDATE**

So far I found out, that it has something to do with the first large table. If I shorten the table to:

```
\ctable[
    cap = {Übersicht der Teilstichproben},
    caption = {Übersicht der Teilstichproben\newline Quelle: \cite{Wagner:2008kq}},
label = Teilstichprobe,
width = 110mm,
pos   = ht,
center,
]{cc>{\hsize=1\hsize\raggedright}X}{
\tnote[a]{Genauer: Haushalte, deren Haushaltsvorstand nicht türkischer, italienischer, jugoslawischer. griechischer oder spanischer Nationalität war. Dies waren ganz überwiegend (99\thinspace\%)  deutsche Haushaltsvorstände.}
\tnote[b]{Genauer: Haushalte, deren Haushaltsvorstand türkischer, italienischer, jugoslawischer. griechischer oder spanischer Nationalität war.}
\tnote[c]{Anstaltshaushalte sind nicht repräsentativ eingeschlossen; sie werden zwar auch nicht ausgeschlossen, wenn sie beim random walk gelistet werden und sind insofern in dem Bruttobestand enthalten, werden aber bei der Durchführung der Befragung in der Regel bei neuen Samples nicht berücksichtigt.}
}{
    \FL
    Stichprobe & Start in & Beschreibung    \NN
    \cmidrule(l){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
    A & 1984 & (Deutsche) Haushalte\tmark[a] in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland (Hauptstichprobe, $N=4528$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    B & 1984 & Ausländische Haushalte\tmark[b] in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland ($N=1393$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    C & 1990 & Privathaushalte in der DDR ($N=2179$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    D & 1994 & Zuwanderer-Privathaushalte in Deutschland ($N=374$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    E & 1998 & Haushalte\tmark[c] in Deutschland (Ergänzungsstichprobe, $N=1056$ realisierte Haushalte)\NN
    F & 2000 & Haushalte\tmark[c] in Deutschland (Ergänzu ) \NN
    $gk_reg_a < 6$   &  -17142 & 11187\LL
}
```

Than the table appears at the right spot. If I add more characters in the next to last row (F) than this table and all following tables were moved to the document end.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the problem is, that the table is to long.

According to the ctable manual, ctable tries to set the table on the next empty page.

> When you make a table wider than \textwidth, it will extend in the
>   right margin. If it is a large table, occupying a whole page, you can
>   use the geometry package and surround your ctable call with
>   \newgeometry{width=...,margin=...} and \restoregeometry. However, both
>   geometry commands imply \clearpage, so your table will appear on an
>   otherwise empty page. [ctable Manual Sec. 4](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ctable/ctable.pdf)

So what I did is to set `\clearpage` befor and after my table. This will set the table on a sperate page. So far so good, but I'm wondering if this is the only solution...?!?